# ubuntu won't boot after install USB\CD

Tags: installation, boot, usb, hp, cd

I want to replace windows with Ubuntu, so I installed it on my hard drive from a USB stick and a CD, but every time I try to install it, and when it gets done installing, i reboot the computer but all i get is a black screen with a small line(the line that marks where you are going to type), like its trying to boot from something but it cant find it (I've tried to install it about 10 times). I have tried to leave the black screen up for 30min to see if it would boot, but nothing. I tried to leave the live Ubuntu up all night to see if it was still installing, but nothing, nothing but that black screen. I've also tried installing it onto my USB stick but when i boot from it it says "PRESS ANY KEY TO REBOOT." and if i press anything it just reboots. So can anyone help?

Computer info:

HP pavilion 520n

Intel(R) Celeron(TM) CPU 1300MHz

1.30 GHz, 512 MB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

IF you got to the point where you were prompted to reboot your system, Ubuntu installed fine. Remove any USD drives and or optical media. Enter your BIOS and make sure the boot order is hard drive first. Please let us know the results. If this does not work disable all boot option EXCEPT the hard drive and retry.

Comment: well i tried what you said but nothing worked :( and the "PRESS ANY KEY TO REBOOT." ONLY comes up when I try to boot from my USB

Answer (score 0):

How much space is there on the hard drive? if there is less than 4 GB then linux cannot install, and 8GB is recommended. It is not an issue with your linux distro if it will install onto a USB though, its something to do with the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was deleting any bits of Ubuntu I had lying around my system, and then booting from the USB. It gave me 3 options:

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- Something else (I can't remember)

I just clicked install Ubuntu and it took me straight to Ubuntu's own installer (same kind of thing as when you first install Windows)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It seems to me that it is not installation problem. Also, most possible scenarios already covered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

When on the grub boot loader, immediately press e the 'e' key and at the line starting with the word Ubuntu. It's the third line I think. The hit the 'end' key and type `nomodeset`. Then hit ctrl-x and that shall be done. Now when the GUI opens, just install the drivers for your graphics card.